# How can I get the Maven Shade plugin to copy an arbitrary file to the jar

Tags: java, maven-2

I am using the Maven Shade plugin to build an executable JAR file for one of my projects.  It works well but I need to include an extra file in the JAR which is not included in other builds (and is not simply picked up from the project's target/ directory).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just put that supplemental file into src/main/resources folder and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider moving (or copying) the file into a maven module instead of fighting against the way the plugin works.